# How to make onclicklistener for new menu item in android

Tags: android

I am adding a menu item for texts selection. normally it shows cut,copy,share, etc.. I added a one more item to this menu and named the item as "Mark".

For this I added the following code in my Activity.Java

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    if (mActionMode == null) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu(); 
        menu.add("Mark");
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

I am able to get my menu item while long press on texts.. Below is the screen, which reflects my menu item.

[image]

For this menu item, I want to do something while select it. So, I used the following code.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if( item.getTitle().equals("Mark")){
        System.out.println("MenuItem Mark clicked----");
        Log.d("MenuItem  clicked----", "Mark");          
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here, I am not able to get the message "MenuItem Mark clicked----" or "MenuItem  clicked---- Mark" in my Logcat.

How may I do this?

### update

Followed Elitz's answer, but still no luck. my Changes below

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    if (mActionMode == null) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();  
        menu.add(0,1000,0,"Mark");
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == 1000) {
         System.out.println("MenuItem Mark clicked----");
         Log.d("MenuItem  clicked----", "Mark");
    }         
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Added updated answer and still no messages came in Logcat

```
private ActionMode.Callback startActionMode = (new ActionMode.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu yourMenu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }       
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu yourMenu) {
        return false;
    }       
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem yourMenu) {
        Log.d("MenuItem  clicked----303", "Mark");
        if (yourMenu.getItemId() == R.attr.actionModeSelectAllDrawable) {
             System.out.println("MenuItem Mark clicked----305");
             Log.d("MenuItem  clicked----", "Mark");
        }         
        return true;
    }
});
```

### update2

Followed Ankesh's answer also,

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    if (mActionMode == null) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();  
        menu.add(R.id.privateText);
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.privateText) {
         System.out.println("MenuItem Mark clicked----");
         Log.d("MenuItem  clicked----", "Mark");
    }         
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Both attempt there is no logs available...

### Update3

For test the other menu, I found id for selectAll menu item in R,java, and tried the following code,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {           if (item.getItemId() == R.attr.actionModeSelectAllDrawable) {
         System.out.println("MenuItem All clicked----");
         Log.d("MenuItem  clicked----", "All");
    }         
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

this is also not showing the message in Logcat. Is this function is right one for menu items selection. or what else I am missing in this?

Comment: Normally you'd use `item.getId() == R.id.menu_mark` or something. See if that works

Comment: You'd have to add an id to the dynamic Menu item to do that, though

Comment: As I am new to android, can you help me how to add mark to R.java so that R.id.menu_mark can be called as you suggest.

Comment: return true  inplace of `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);`

Comment: Instead of getTitle use getId and match it with id

Comment: All, as all of you people suggested a one thing, can you pls post your answers with how to add my menu item to be dynamic and can be called in onOptionsItemSelected method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this instead of your `menu.add("Mark");`

```
add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title);
```

now you have your `Id` now you can check for that.

`groupId = 0;` and `order = 0;`, or any number that fits your choice, but since in your example you have only 1 group, just put 0.

hmm.. i think you got us all fooled :) yes it will not work, because you are using `ActionMode` right and with `ActionMode` you need to specify a callback for it,  so you should put your code here

```
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem arg1) {
        return false;
    }
```

in its callback. like something like this, when you call startActoinMode

```
startActionMode(new ActionMode.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu yourMenu) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }       
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu yourMenu) {
        return false;
    }       
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem yourMenu) {
        //put your item click here
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Ratwanska try inflating before adding your new menu in code and see

Comment: Elitz, Added your code, pls take a look my update... Still its not showing message...

Comment: in which callback are you creating the menu? and you used id 1000 rather than R.attr.actionModeSelectAllDrawable. if you don't so as not to waste time show me the full .java class so i rectify it for you.@Ratwanska you could use pastebin.com to post the full class and give me the link i will edit it and let you copy back

Comment: Elitz sorry for taking your time.. Pls see my complete code here (http://pastebin.com/Yh7vpJrp). Need your help in this indeed... Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry sorry i forgot about this sorry @Ratwanska i will give you a solution soon, sorry, that is if you have solved it. very sorry for the delay, had too many notifications and i didnt see it

Comment: @Ratwanska [check this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112256/quick-conversation)

Comment: Elitz, thanks for your answer. Sorry for my delay. This works good on button click, but in webview while long press on the texts, it shows only normal menu items. Is it possible to rewrite them?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.xyz) { 

}
```

Comment: You might be having a Menu.xlm file in resource folder. There in item block add id

Comment: As you are dynamically adding Menu item, use :- add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title) as mentioned by @Elltz in answer to this question.

Comment: How are you getting this menu with items Share,Find,Websearch,etc...? Is this overflow menu ( three dots )

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add your menu item inside your xml menu(I mean inside `R.menu.main`)? And after that just detect the item click inside this method:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_id:
            //TODO click detected!!
            break
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Its that or I don't understand your question :)